# Rob Lowe said "I won't work for (Orion Pictures) again for all the money in the world" in 1984. Is that what happened?

Tags: film-industry, the-hotel-new-hampshire

Wikipedia's [The Hotel New Hampshire (film); Box office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hotel_New_Hampshire_(film)#Box_office) section says:

> [...] Based on an estimated $7.5 million budget<sup>2</sup>, this can be considered a box office bomb.
>
> Rob Lowe later said "When some studios do get a good movie, a movie that's different, they kill it. **Orion – I hate that studio; I won't work for them again for all the money in the world** – releases Hotel New Hampshire with a cartoon of a bear: people thought they were going to see Garfield the Cat. Then they change it to a bicycle for five: people thought they were going to see the Von Trapp family."<sup>6</sup>
>
> <sup>2</sup>https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087428/
>
> <sup>6</sup>*Rob Lowe has more on his mind than hordes of squealing girls* Scott, Jay. The Globe and Mail, 28 Sep 1984: E.3.

It's been 36 years, did Robe Lowe ever work for that movie studio again? I don't find a search feature for cross-referencing actors with studios in the [Oracle of Bacon](https://oracleofbacon.org/) nor from what I could find in [IMDB's Collaborations and Overlaps search help](https://www.imdb.com/find?q=rob%20lowe&s=tt&ttype=ft&ref_=fn_ft) and Lowe has been in nearly 50 films to date, so it's quite a challenge to search each individually.

Instead, I think that it's quite possible that there is a follow-up to this already known, like a list of actors who said they'd never work for studio X but did, so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: Can someone have a look to see if there are other tags that apply? *Thanks!*

Comment: I’m not sure if M&TV.SE is meant to be a crowd sourced movie search. To me this seems like a trivia question. Note that the 101 actor listings for Lowe on IMDb include TV appearances. He has not been in 100 movies.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm not sure either, but I don't think that this is that. A decision to *never* work for a movie studio again at the beginning of an actor's career is a monumental decision, and to announce it so publicly has consequences. This would not be considered "trivia" by any of the parties involved. Conversely, just about any question in this site is arguably trivia. I don't know how likely one could win such an argument on a case-by-case basis, but how trivial versus how profound a bit of information about a movie really is, is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @ToddWilcox just fyi here's a venue for further discussion: [How to judge ahead of time if people will think my question is "movie trivia" and perhaps unsuitable for the site?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4738/45856)

Comment: @uhoh Triviality is indeed partially subjective. And obviously relative, as you illustrate. But that is the problem right there: you can always find perspectives from which trivia is significant. The point is that 'trivia' on this platform is quite accurately (and increasingly) defined according to the needs and intention of this platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It looks like he was as good as his word.

According to Wikipedia's [list of Orion Pictures films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Orion_Pictures_films) and its [Rob Lowe filmography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Lowe#Filmography), Rob Lowe has appeared in only one Orion Pictures film since *The Hotel New Hampshire*: a 2016 thriller called [*Pocket Listing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_Listing_(film)). However, it appears that Orion only picked up the film for distribution after it was produced by Mythmaker Productions, Helios Productions, and Brad Jabour Films in association with Montana Moon Productions, according to [this article](https://deadline.com/2016/11/pocket-listing-theatrical-release-2016-rob-lowe-burt-reynolds-1201848696/). Although the film wound up being an Orion Pictures release, Rob Lowe probably had no way of knowing that this would be the case when he agreed to appear in it or while it was in production.

Comment: The Orion Pictures of 2016 has barely anything to do with the Orion Pictures of 1984 anyway: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Pictures